# Initialising a subclass of an abstract class inside a method using Depenency Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an application that uses an abstract class.
The abstract class has a static concrete method used by the application class to determine which subclass of the abstract class should be initialized (according to input to application class) to do the typeSpecific task.

Although I am using guice to inject the dependency A into the application class.

Is the if else logic in the application class to initialize the "typeOfInput" bad coding style.
Since, I am using guice to initialize Dependency "A" but using "new" to initialize the subclasses both in the same class.
Is there any way the "typeOfInput" can be initialized using DI.

May seem silly to some people, but I am a beginner.
Thanks in advance

```
public class Application {

    private final Dependency a;
    private AbstractClass typeOfInput;
    private static final TypeOfInput typeA = some_constant_value;

    @Inject
    Application(final Dependency a){
          this.a = a;
    }


    public doTask(final InputData inputData) {

        if(AbstractClass.getInputType(inputData) == typeA){
          typeOfInput = new classExtendingAbstractClassOne(a);      
        }else{
          typeOfInput = new classExtendingAbstractClassTwo(a);       
        }

    typeOfInput.doTypeSpecificTask();
    }

}
```

```
abstract class AbstractClass{

    //Concrete method
    static TypeOfInput getTypeOfInput(final InputData inputData) {
          //Does some processing and returns TypeOfInput value
    }
    abstract void doTypeSpecificTask();
}
```

```
class classExtendingAbstractClassOne extends AbstractClass {

        void doTypeSpecificTask() {
               //DO something relevant to this type
        }      

}
```

```
class classExtendingAbstractClassTwo extends AbstractClass {

        void doTypeSpecificTask() {
               //DO something relevant to this type
        }      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `doTask` modifies internal state of `Application`, which brings extra limitations without any obvious benefit. Now your `Application` instance is not thread-safe, cannot be safely used with multiple threads.

So probably you don't need to look for ways to apply DI here. However it would be a good idea to try converting `typeOfInput` into a local variable instead.